# NSString * Discards Qualifiers

Tags: objective-c, core-text

Why am i getting an 'NSString *' discards qualifiers on currentTextB on third line "CFAttributedStringSetAtribute(currentTextB..."

```
CFAttributedStringRef currentTextB = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);

CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"Helvetica", 10.0f, nil);
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentTextB,CFRangeMake(0, strLength-1),kCTFontAttributeName,font);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `CFAttributedStringSetAttribute()` must be a *mutable*
attributed string. Example:

```
CFStringRef stringRef = CFSTR("foo");

// Create mutable attributed string from CFStringRef:
CFMutableAttributedStringRef currentTextB = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(NULL, 0);
CFAttributedStringReplaceString(currentTextB, CFRangeMake(0, 0), stringRef);

// Set an attribute:
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Helvetica"), 10.0f, NULL);
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(currentTextB,
                               CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(currentTextB)),
                               kCTFontAttributeName,font);
```

Alternatively, work with the Foundation type `NSMutableAttributedString` which 
is "toll-free bridged" to `CFMutableAttributedStringRef` and therefore can be used
interchangeably:

```
NSString *string = @"foo";
NSMutableAttributedString *currentTextB = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:nil];
NSFont *font = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
[currentTextB addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

Comment: how can i populate stringRef with a nstring var? This CFStringRef stringRef = CFSTR(myString); instead of this CFStringRef stringRef = CFSTR("foo"); I'm getting an error of "expected ')' for some reason when i try the var

Comment: @user520300: CFStringRef and NSString are "toll-free bridged", so you can just assign `CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)(string)`. - Alternatively, work directly with NSString and NSMutableAttributedString, see updated answer.